# MySQL sum calculation with multiple groups and subgroups

Tags: mysql

I have a query which does not output the result I want. I spent several days on this, but I did not find a solution.

My Code

```sql
SELECT *, IFNULL(type, 'N/A') AS groupField, IFNULL(type, 'N/A') AS displayField, `pmonth`, `pyear`, count(prj.code) as projects_num 
    FROM `tblProjecats` `prj` 
    LEFT JOIN ( select cda, pyear, pmonth, sum(venituri) venituri, sum(cheltuieli) cheltuieli, sum(if(cont3 between 500 and 550,cheltuieli,0)) cheltuieliD, sum(if(cont3 > 550,cheltuieli,0)) cheltuieliI from buffer_cda group by pyear, pmonth, cda ) cda ON `cda`.`cda`=`prj`.`code` 
    -- more simple left jons --
    WHERE (concat(pyear,lpad(pmonth,2,0)) BETWEEN 201811 AND 201911) 
    GROUP BY `type`, concat_ws('', `cda`.`pyear`, lpad(cda.pmonth, 2, '0')) 
    ORDER BY `type` ASC, `pyear` ASC, `pmonth` ASC, `cda` ASC
```

Table tblProjects

```
code    type
66666   N/A
66667   Custom
66668   Simple
66669   Simple
66610   N/A
66611   Custom
66612   N/A
```

Table buffer_cda (with project Type joined for easier visualization)

```
cda pmonth  pyear   type    cheltuieliD
66666   1   2019    N/A     1
66667   1   2019    Custom  10
66668   1   2019    Simple  100
66669   12  2018    Simple  200
66610   12  2018    N/A     2
66611   12  2018    Custom  20
66612   12  2018    N/A     3
66612   12  2018    N/A     4
```

Expected result

```
Type    pmonth  pyear   count_prj   cheltuieliD
N/A     12      2018        2       9
N/A     1       2019        1       1
Custom  12      2018        1       20
Custom  1       2019        1       10
Simple  12      2018        1       200
Simple  1       2019        1       100
```

Actual result

```
Type    pmonth  pyear   count_prj   cheltuieliD
N/A     12      2018        2       7
N/A     1       2019        8       1
Custom  12      2018        1       20
Custom  1       2019        3       10
Simple  12      2018        1       200
Simple  1       2019        1       100
```

I am doing something wrong with groupings but I do not know what. In other cases I have a duplicate Type results with cheltuieliD= 2 and cheltuieliD= 7 (instead of one type with cheltuieliD=9)

Next step on this would be calculating the cheltuieliD indicator on each project type, on Period Groups (month/Year) and then a grand total. Is this possible with a single query?

Comment: I'm trying to run this with the same data you provided but where are these fields: `venituri`, `cheltuieli`, and `cont3`?

Comment: 'with project Type joined for easier visualisation' - isn't helpful you should only include sample data as it is. - I assume buffer_cda does not contain a column called type?

Answer (score 0):

Chnge your groupby sequence with cda, pyear, pmonth...

If you just want to return project count every month then remove cda frim groupby clause...

If you could explain what logical operation you want to perform we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Your data does not seem to be representative of your problem but given the sample data provided I would code like this

```
 drop table if exists tblprojects,buffer_cda;
 create table tblProjects
(code int,   type varchar(20));
insert into tblprojects values
(66666  , 'N/A'),
(66667  , 'Custom'),
(66668  , 'Simple'),
(66669  , 'Simple'),
(66610  , 'N/A'),
(66611  , 'Custom'),
(66612  , 'N/A');

create Table buffer_cda 
(cda int,pmonth int, pyear int, cheltuieliD int);
insert into buffer_cda values
(66666  , 1   ,2019  , 1),
(66667  , 1   ,2019  , 10),
(66668  , 1   ,2019  , 100),
(66669  , 12  ,2018  , 200),
(66610  , 12  ,2018  , 2),
(66611  , 12  ,2018  , 20),
(66612  , 12  ,2018  , 3),
(66612  , 12  ,2018  , 4);

select type,pmonth,pyear,count(type),sum(cheltuieliD) 
from tblprojects tp
join buffer_cda bc on bc.cda = tp.code
group by type,pyear,pmonth;

+--------+--------+-------+-------------+------------------+
| type   | pmonth | pyear | count(type) | sum(cheltuieliD) |
+--------+--------+-------+-------------+------------------+
| Custom |     12 |  2018 |           1 |               20 |
| Custom |      1 |  2019 |           1 |               10 |
| N/A    |     12 |  2018 |           3 |                9 |
| N/A    |      1 |  2019 |           1 |                1 |
| Simple |     12 |  2018 |           1 |              200 |
| Simple |      1 |  2019 |           1 |              100 |
+--------+--------+-------+-------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct way!

Thank you all for your responses!

I had to swap joining buffer_cda on projects to projects joining to buffer_cda.
More on, I had to eliminate other joins.

Bellow my answer, written for codeigniter!

```
    $this->db->select("*,IFNULL(".$groupField.", 'N/A') AS groupField, IFNULL(".$displayField.", 'N/A') AS displayField, luna,anul,
            count(DISTINCT prj.code) as projects_num,
            sum(if(cont3 between 500 and 550,cheltuieli,0)) AS cheltuieliD,
            sum(if(cont3 > 550,cheltuieli,0)) cheltuieliI,
            sum(if(cont3 between 500 and 550,cheltuieli,0))/count(DISTINCT prj.code) AS cheltuieliDAvg,
            sum(if(cont3 > 550,cheltuieli,0))/count(DISTINCT prj.code) cheltuieliIAvg

            ");

    $this->db->from('buffer_cda cda');
    $this->db->join('(
        select * from tblProjects ) prj', 'cda.cda=prj.code', 'LEFT');
```

I also grouped by type, pyear, pmonth.